# CSS font size different in chrome and firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, font-size

I'm trying to understand how can I force Chrome and Firefox to show the text of the same size identically.

Let's take next very simple css:

```
body {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

The text in Chrome looks as expected - 16px, but in Firefox it looks like 18px on the screen (the size of the text is still 16px according to Firebug). I also tried to use 16px instead of 1em, but it didn't change anything at all. Both Chrome and Firefox have 100% zoom level.

So, is it possible somehow to force Firefox to show the text exactly of 16px, because the difference of 2px looks realy bad?

**Update - problem solution**

After a couple of hours spent to find a solution I noticed that *layout.css.devPixelsPerPx* setting in Firefox about:config is set to **-1.0**. I changed it to value **1.0** and now it looks identically in Chrome and Firefox. So, it looks like I changed this setting a long time ago and then I have forgotten about it - be careful when changing browser settings :)

Comment: Can you post screenshot (it would be nice if you capture it along with the "box" highlighted by Firebug).

Comment: It looks like it might be a feature! http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/962990. I haven't used Firefox for a while after switching to Chrome (sorry Mozilla) so was not aware of this change.

Comment: Are you positive you made that change and it didn't come as a pre-set because I am experiencing the same issue and I know I never played around with those settings.